# Meaning of error when using CartoDB to georeference spreadsheet?

Tags: carto, geocoding

I linked my CartoDB map to a spreadsheet in Google Docs that has column headings of Name, City, State, and Pledge. However, when I try to georeference the spreadsheet, for the cities, I get an error that says "no polygon data available for your selection." What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

That means that in our internal geocoder we don't have the polygon boundary for a city, just a point where it is located.

As an analog example, you can check that for countries, states, counties, zipcodes (in USA; CAN; FRA; ESP; AUS) we have polygons.

This just means that we don't have that information available. If you have special needs, you can contact us and we'll try to redirect you to a source where you would be able to get the data (if any). We also are offering the Common-Data section (upper-right corner link in the dashboard) where interesting datasets (like congressional districts in the US) are available.

We work everyday to increase the information there's in our internal geocoder and also in the common-data section :-)